# iPhone 6 shows charging icon but not charging

Tags: battery, charging, iphone

Recently my iPhone stopped charging at all. I took it to a local mobile shop in Pakistan; they changed my charger and it started charging, then all of a sudden it stopped. It shows the charging icon but the battery percentage was not increasing, rather decreasing.

They told me to change the port, so I did and now it is charging from only one side of the USB cable. I have tried different other cables as well and different other chargers too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the problem is that there is dirt/dust inside the connector (lightning) port.

Try cleaning with a toothpick (plastic is the best) to remove possible dirt from the port.

Comment: removed dust..even got it changed..now its giving this proble.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the problem with the battery.Just get a new battery and it should be fine, no need to replace ic port